# JavaScript code Chrome Extension background page sometimes needs refresh of page in order to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I decided to make a super simple chrome extension for a colleague, because at work we have an online platform of sorts that has some annoying fields containing huge numbers that you sometimes need on your clipboard (ctrl + v) for ease of use, but you have to type them by hand and until we add a shortcut or some other fix globally I made this simple extension that adds a click handler on a div element after our page is loaded and when you click with the mouse it gets the much needed number on your clipboard and you can simply press ctrl+V and simply paste it.

I'm quite a rookie in Chrome Extension Development, so I accept all advice, but for now I put all of the above logic in a content script and in **manifest.json** I have added the url of the page it needs to run on, plus a jquery.js file on the same page just for easier selection of elements. So the code right now is:

**contentscript.js**

```
$('myselector').click(function() {
  let annoyingNumber = $(otherSelector);
  setClipboardText(annoyingNumber);
});

function setClipboardText(text) {
  var id = 'mycustom-clipboard-textarea-hidden-id';
  var existsTextarea = document.getElementById(id);

  if (!existsTextarea) {
    // console.log('Creating textarea');
    var textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
    textarea.id = id;
    // Place in top-left corner of screen regardless of scroll position.
    textarea.style.position = 'fixed';
    textarea.style.top = 0;
    textarea.style.left = 0;

    // Ensure it has a small width and height. Setting to 1px / 1em
    // doesn't work as this gives a negative w/h on some browsers.
    textarea.style.width = '1px';
    textarea.style.height = '1px';

    // We don't need padding, reducing the size if it does flash render.
    textarea.style.padding = 0;

    // Clean up any borders.
    textarea.style.border = 'none';
    textarea.style.outline = 'none';
    textarea.style.boxShadow = 'none';

    // Avoid flash of white box if rendered for any reason.
    textarea.style.background = 'transparent';
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(textarea);
    // console.log('The textarea now exists');
    existsTextarea = document.getElementById(id);
  } else {
    // console.log('The textarea already exists')
  }

  existsTextarea.value = text;
  existsTextarea.select();

  try {
    var status = document.execCommand('copy');
    if (!status) {
      console.error('Cannot copy text');
    } else {
      console.log('The text is now on the clipboard');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Unable to copy.');
  }
}
```

I should hurriedly say that the code for **setClipboardText()** function is not by any means mine, but was taken from a google search and it is open to use (or so I understood), as I said I simply wanted to help a colleague out, so of course I didn't want to waste too much time on developing my own copyToClipboard when it's already available.

if needed **manifest.json**

```
{ 
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "name",
    "content_scripts": [{ 
      "matches": ["someUrl.com"],
      "js": ["jquery.min.js", "contentscript.js"]
    }]
}
```

So everything above works just fine for the first 30 minutes, or hour or so, but the problem is that after some time passes without the browser reloading it simply stops working and after a page refresh it's all fine once again. So my question is, has anyone ever stump on something similar as a problem and if you've found a fix for it?

PS. All I've thought of right now is maybe trying to use a background page instead of contentScript, but 1) I didn't really know how to include jQuery to background page and 2) I somehow need to add the .click() after a certain page is loaded, so I'm not sure how would I achieve this through a background page as well.

Comment: There are no known reasons. The code looks correct. And content script is the only method of accessing a webpage, be it declared in manifest or injected from a background page. The issue must be something specific to the site. Try looking in the web console (F12 key). If there's nothing helpful, try adding more `console.log` in code to help see where it fails.

Comment: First guess: some script on the page changes/updates the element (or an ancestor of the element, including the element) on which you have your click handler. Also possible is that a handler was added before yours in the event propagation (although less likely to have happened so long after the page loaded). Try adding your event handler to the `window` using capture (i.e. not with jQuery) and only react when the `event.target` matches your selector. Alt: use a named function for the event handler (so not added multiple times) and a `setInterval` that periodically re-adds it as a handler.

Comment: Better would be to investigate the scripts on the page to see what is causing the issue. But, that may might take more effort, depending on the complexity of the page, than just trying a workaround to see if it solves the issue.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions @Makyen, you gave me some good ideas to test out, probably would take some time, since I'm doing this off working hours, but I would reply here if any of your suggestions lead to a solution. Thanks once again! :)